# Series variable resistance with NPN transistor

Tags: transistors, filter, low-pass

i'm trying to build a symple voltage controlled low pass filter and in the design they ask for a transconductance amplifier (which works as a series resistance in the R C pair for the passive low pass).

But the order i made for my parts came out wrong and i got a triac instead of the transconductance ampplifier...

so i was wondering if i could use a NPN transistor as the variable resistance kinda like what i did in my voltage controlled oscilator design

[image: voltage controlled resistance]

so i tried to use that NPN in place of the series resistor of the low pass filter and it didn't work...

i imagine it's because the emitter is not tied to ground or something like that.

so there are two solutions to my problem: one is to find a low pass topology with the resistor that controls the cutoff point tied to ground and the other one is to find a way of making an NPN transistor work as a series resistance.

i also tried the first solution by using the active low pass topology and replacing the feedback resistor like so:

[image]

also didn't work

maybe i'll try to replace the feedforward resistor with the transistor as well
but it might be some error in the assembly of the circuit

so now i'm kinda stuck

any ideas?

Comment: BJTs are more like current sinks than variable resistances. JFETs are more applicable. But I think the OTA will be better.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can only have small EB voltages between cutoff and saturation on the BJT. May 0.6 -0.8V on many general purpose BJTs.

Comment: well, sure, Sphero. I'd love to use the OTA but i currently don't have it :(

good reminder, scienceGeyser. i haven't checked that but with the oscilator the usable range was from 450mV to about 650mV

Comment: If it’s  possible to control collector current  on a constant voltage then ok using a small AC voltage on a larger DC bias. Also the input is easier with emitter grounded and Vin+ @ some dc with gain. Thus feedback to U1 uses Vin- and U2 is inverting =  -1

Comment: Then use U4 for AC gain and DC balance. Otherwise analog switched R’s can work for some apps. But these are bandaids

Comment: 70s analog audio synth, i.e. Moog, used this kind of BJT voltage controlled filter heavily. Maybe you could look at those for inspiration. Otherwise, JFET.

Comment: Yes.but no Op Amps. Save a few 741 front ends. You haven’t define you desired gain and transfer function range yet.

Comment: The moog filter is an alternative i guess...
but i'd still like to try the korg style filter 
as for a transfer function range i believe you mean bandwidth? and it's very very low frequency. like a max of 10Hz or something like that.(that is for the control voltage, ofc)

Comment: ah so you planned something like [this](https://www.schmitzbits.de/ms20.html) ?

Comment: So I've never tried anything like it, but based [this other example](https://electro-music.com/forum/topic-68205.html), maybe in your version you might want the emitters going to a low impedance node (but consider the overall direction of the current relative to the op amps), and a large base resistance to your control voltage (i.e. controlled by a current)

Comment: Darn. I'm learning stuff from this. Thanks for the links @PeteW!

Comment: yes, that's the schematic i'm following. But i don't have the OTAs :(

Comment: @jonk -- so am I!!